# Inconvenient to validate negative number

Tags: c

I have this code

```
    int n;
    char c;

    while ((scanf("%d%c", &n, &c) != 2)|| c != '\n' && n >= 0)
    {
        while( getchar() != '\n' );
    }
```

I do not understand why does not detect if the input is a negative number, I just want to read positive numbers

Someone sees the problem?

Comment: problem of priority with operators (....) || ... && ....   this style not very clear !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the condition the following way

```
while ( (scanf("%d%c", &n, &c) != 2) || c != '\n' || n < 0)
```